Add the UK countries (England, Scotland etc) to the 'Country' field in Craft 5?
I know this is politically sensitive to some (!) — we have a website where we'd be able to select the different countries in the United Kingdom via the country field.
So, as well as my client being able to select 'Germany' as a project country, I'd like to be able to select 'England' or 'Scotland' rather than being forced to use 'United Kingdom'!
I'm guessing it means customising the 'country' model underpinning the field, but no idea where to start with that!
Running Craft 5.4.9 in this install...

What kind of data that your "Country" option will have, like the current Country Field will have
#countryCode: "AF",
#name: "Afghanistan",
#threeLetterCode: "AFG",
#numericCode: "004",
#currencyCode: "AFN",
#locale: "en",
if your custom field is going to only have 2 kind of data, then you might want to create custom field that extends Dropdown instead of Country

It seems that Scotland, England, Wales etc do not have ISO codes. I want my client to be able to select ANY country in the world, but ALSO Scotland, England etc...

Although ISO 3166-2:GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:GB#Second-level_subdivisions) does allow for subdivisions of the United Kingdom... Im still unclear how to extract this from the country field though :)
